# VSCode script type="text/html" does not provide html intellisense features

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, intellisense

enable the intellisense features (such as autocomplete tag names, property suggestions, etc.) when I am editing a script of type text/html inside an html file

Hi all,
I am using VSCode and would like to enable the intellisense features (such as autocomplete tag names, property suggestions, etc.) when i am editing a script of type text/html inside an html file.

For example:

```
<script type="text/html">

  <div id="myid"></div>

</script>
```

Color coding is OK, VSCode seem to recognise it as HTML and syntax highlighting / coloring is there. However, the problem is the intellisense features do not exist. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a specific setting?

is this supported by VSCode? I can't seem to find a definitive answer. I am using latest VSCode 1.36

Comment: You can check if this was mentioned already in an issue over at the VS Code Github repo. If not, feel free to open an issue there.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: there are almost 6000 open issues !! :) this is why i am asking here.  I checked and i t is unclear to me if the same issue is one of the open ones.. therefore I ask here, if someone using vscode and has knowledge about this.. thanks